# Dialogflow fulfillment not showing suggestions on Google Assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I've written my own library to respond to a Dialog Fulfillment webhook, but it's not working as the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#webhookresponse) say that it should.

When my webhook is used for fulfilment the simple text response works, but suggestion chips do not. The "RESPONSE" tab in the Dialogflow console shows the response from my webhook:

```
{
  "outputContexts": [ ],
  "fulfillmentText": "Hi, how can I help you?",
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
    { "text": {"text": ["Hi, how can I help you?"]} },
    { "suggestions": {"suggestions": [{"title": "Looking for a job"}]} }
  ],
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "expectedInputs": [{
          "possibleIntents": [{"intent": "actions.intent.TEXT"}, {"intent": "JobSearch"}],
          "speechBiasingHints": ["looking for a job"],
          "inputPrompt": {
            "richInitialPrompt": {
              "items": [
                {"simpleResponse": { "textToSpeech": "Hi, How can I help you?"}}
              ],
              "suggestions": [{"title": "Looking for a job"}]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When I disable my webhook and and provide a response message and suggestions in the console the suggestions do show, but the RESPONSE tab looks more like my `payload.google` field:

```
{
  "conversationToken": "[]",
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "expectedInputs": [
    {
      "inputPrompt": {
        "richInitialPrompt": {
          "items": [
            {"simpleResponse": {"textToSpeech": "Response from Dialogflow"}}
          ],
          "suggestions": [{"title": "Dialogflow suggestion"}]
        }
      },
      "possibleIntents": [{"intent": "assistant.intent.action.TEXT"}],
      "speechBiasingHints": []
    }
  ],
  "responseMetadata": {
    "status": {"message": "Success (200)"},
    "queryMatchInfo": {"queryMatched": true, "intent": "..."}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh - the `payload` in the [Dialogflow webhook response](https://developers.google.com/actions/build/json/dialogflow-webhook-json#dialogflow-response-body) does NOT have the same format as the [Conversation webhook response](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse).

They have similarities, but also important differences.